# Why is my javascript not carrying out my "if" statements in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code here.

1. It is creating the correct `noOfChoices` when I `console.log` it, I can see it. But it is not executing the `if (noOfChoices === "2") {}` scenarios. Can someone please help make this work (see the commented out area in code), thanks.
2. Also, how can I run `diceRoll` during this function then use the constants (`randomNumber1`- `randomNumber4`) that I got in this roll in the code following? (see the commented out part towards the end)

```
<!--begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!--language: lang - js-->

    let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')
links.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        let numberOfChoices = event.target.innerText
        document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').innerHTML = `${numberOfChoices}<span class="caret"></span>`

        if (numberOfChoices === "2") {
            $("#img3, #img4, .threeChoices, .fourChoices").addClass("invisible")
        }
        if (numberOfChoices === "3") {
            $("#img4, .fourChoices").addClass("invisible");
            $("#img3, .threeChoices").removeClass("invisible")
        }
        if (numberOfChoices === "4") {
            $("#img3, #img4, .threeChoices, 
                .fourChoices ").removeClass("
        invisible ");
    }
    })
})

// Responding to Submit
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Storing Data into variables
    var choice1 = $("#choice1").val();
    var choice2 = $("#choice2").val();
    var choice3 = $("#choice3").val();
    var choice4 = $("#choice4").val();
    var noOfChoices = $("#dropdownMenu").text();

    // Rotate animation
    $(".dice").addClass("rotate");

    // Changing text to user input
    $("#caption1").html(choice1);
    $("#caption2").html(choice2);
    $("#caption3").html(choice3);
    $("#caption4").html(choice4);
    console.log(noOfChoices);

    // THE FOLLOWING IS NOT WORKING DESPITE noOfChoices BEING CORRECT IN THE PREVIOUS LINE
    if (noOfChoices === "2") {
        $("#caption1, #caption2").removeClass("invisible");
        $("#caption3, #caption4").addClass("invisible");
    }

    if (noOfChoices === "3") {
        $("#caption1, #caption2, #caption3").removeClass("invisible");
        $("#caption4").addClass("invisible");
    }

    if (noOfChoices === "4") {
        $(".caption").removeClass("invisible");
    }

    $("#submit").html("Again");


    // SEE HERE IS THE SECOND PROBLEM:
    // Rolling Dice
    diceRoll();

    // Determining winner
    if (noOfChoices === "2") {
        if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2) {
            $("#title").html(choice1 + "wins! ");
        } else if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1) {
            $("#title").html(choice2 + "wins! ");
        } else if (randomNumber2 = randomNumber1) {
            $("#title").html("Oops, try again!");
        }


    }

})



function diceRoll() {
    // 1st dice
    var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    var Image1 = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", Image1);

    // 2nd dice
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    var Image2 = "dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png";
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[2].setAttribute("src", Image2);

    // 3rd dice
    var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    var Image3 = "dice" + randomNumber3 + ".png";
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[3].setAttribute("src", Image3);

    // 4th dice
    var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    var Image4 = "dice" + randomNumber3 + ".png";
    document.querySelectorAll("img")[4].setAttribute("src", Image4);
}

<!--end snippet-->
```

Comment: 1. Ensure you're comparing the correct types. Try `console.log(typeof noOfChoices, noOfChoices);` to confirm. Then try comparing with correct typing: `if(String(noOfChoices) === "2")`.
2. You could try returning results from the function: `var [randomNumber1, randomNumber2] = diceRoll();` and `return [randomNumber1, randomNumber2];` inside diceRoll.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** on hindsight you're using `.innerText` which returns strings anyways. So this answer is probably wrong, but I'll leave it here nonetheless. @Eugen Sunic's comment should be the correct answer.

---

Most probably it's a type problem, try using the number type. The differences are shown here:

```
if (numberOfChoices === "2") {
                        ^ this is a string

if (numberOfChoices === 2) {
                        ^ this is a number
```

Or if you want type coercion (which I wouldn't recommend) don't use the `===` operator but `==`, like this:

```
if (numberOfChoices == "2") {
                     ^ coerce numberOfChoices to string, then compare strings
```

Both solutions should work but the first one is better in my *personal* opinion because it leads to stricter code practices.

Comment: Where is his comment please?

Comment: it is gone, but it was about trimming the string like this: `.innerText.trim()`.